# Using Watir-Webdriver, how can I automate the output of all the elements in an array in a totally random order

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Using Watir-Webdriver, how can I automate the output of all the elements in an array in a totally random order. My array has 9 items which are pulled from a CMS and the items are pulled into a list which is numbered 1,2,3,4,.... but in a complete random order each time.

Unfortunately I do not have an example or screenshot to share and do not expect a full solution to my issue. If someone can just point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Watir-webdriver is a functional test tool for web sites. It doesn't inherently output arrays. Do you want to parse a page using Ruby and create an array from page elements? Or are you really asking how to test that a resultset is complete, without relying on output order?

Comment: I think we need a little better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.   For example are you trying to make sure that all elements in the array you get from the CMS are present on the site, once and only once, irrespective of the order?   Or are you trying to test that the CMS is properly randomizing the order of the elements on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a Ruby question that Watir-webdriver.  Speaking purely to the question as answered (which frankly I think is masking a larger challenge you are facing) I would do the following

1) shuffle the array.  [the `.shuffle` method has been built in from at least ruby 1.8.7 onward](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-shuffle).
2) then use either `.each` or `.each_with_index` to traverse the now randomized array